# Call View Model in Class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I need to Use the View model to work like a Listener but my Problem is how to call the view model in kotlin class to observe the target Attribute

```
class ExoPlayerWrapper(){
  init {
    initializePlayer()
// the next part of code need a lifecycle owner as Input to initilize the 
// Provider and my class is not lifecycle owner
    mLoginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
//mLoginViewModel.observe 
}
```

Comment: do you want to initialize `LoginViewModel` in `ExoPlayerWrapper` class?

Comment: Your viewmodel should be tied up to a lifecycle owner. Your wrapper is obviously not one.

Comment: Yes i want to initialize LoginViewModel in ExoPlayerWrapper class @AbuYousuf

Comment: I think so but what is the Solution?? Should i mark my class as lifecycle owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem to be a view, why not use just a simple LiveData?

```
class ExoPlayerWrapper {

  private val _events = MutableLiveData<String>(
  val events: LiveData<String>
    get() = _events


  init {
    initializePlayer()
    value = "stop"
  }

  // Example method
  private fun notifyPause() {
    _events.value = "pause"
  }

}

// Then outside
class SomeClass(player: ExoPlayerWrapper) {

  init {
    player.events.observeForever { event -> /* handle event */ }
  }

}
```

Comment: I think this is the Solution but What if i have all my Observers in one view model and i want to use it in all my app

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing ***ViewModelProviders.of(context)*** Method.  Try this like:

```
viewModel =  ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CheckoutViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: It is Deprecated i want to avoid using Deprecated code but thanks